# Is this PHP Email Form Secure from injections or other abuses?

Tags: php, security

I am new to PHP and put this contact page together using the w3Schools.com example as a guide along with a couple other sources. As far as I can tell, it works fine, but before I put it up on my page I would like to know if there is any potential for abuse. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>

<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
function spamCheck($field) {
    $field = filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 
    if (filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
    $mailcheck = spamCheck($_REQUEST['email']);
    if ($mailcheck == false) {
        echo "Invalid Input";
    } else {
        $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $body = "From\n" . $from . "\n\n"  .  $_REQUEST['message'];
        $to = "<REMOVED>";
        $subject = "$_REQUEST['subject'];
        $host = "<REMOVED>";
        $port = "<REMOVED>";
        $username = "<REMOVED>";  
        $password = "<REMOVED>";
        $headers = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',array ('host' => $host,
             'port' => $port,
             'auth' => true,
             'username' => $username,
             'password' => $password));
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
            echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } else {
            echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
        }
}



} else {
    echo "<h1>Send me an email if you like.</h1>
    <br><form method='post' action='contact.php'><br>
    <p>Your Email: <input name='email' type='text'>
    Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'></p>
    <p>Message:<br>
    <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
    </textarea><br>
    <input type='submit'></p>
    </form>";
}   
?>
</body>
<?php include "footer.php"?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're `spamCheck` function isn't really doing a proper check. It's removing all the invalid characters from the e-mail address and then checking if it's valid, so even if the e-mail had invalid characters it would still passes.

For example:

```
$dangerousEmail = "localhost\nCc:recipient@beingspammed.com";

// This will output "Email is valid!" even though it isn't
if(spamCheck($dangerousEmail))
    echo "Email is valid!";
```

A better check would be just to use `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` directly:

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    // Sanitize the e-mail to be extra safe.
    // I think Pear Mail will automatically do this for you
    $email = filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    echo "Email is valid!";
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the find of feedback I was hoping for. Thank you very much. I see the error in my logic.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that I should validate THEN sanitize in all cases?

Answer (score 5):

I use a blank input field in the form and hide it with css.  If the field exists upon form submit, I know it's spam and just ignore it.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="email2" style="display:none;" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php if (!$_POST['email2']) { // not spam } ?>
```

Of course this only works with bots and spammers who scrape sites to get all the input fields, but since I've implemented it, it's worked great.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is interested I was able to increase the security somewhat. After some research, I think that I have made it more secure, from spammers, at least. I implemented a [captcha by Securimage](http://www.phpcaptcha.org). It was pretty simple to use and I tested it out and think it does a fine job. They have good documentation and a simple quickstart guide right [here](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/). I am going to spend some more time learning about it, but it was quick and easy to get up and running.